# Trying to find customers who have bought brand 1, only brand 2 and customers who have just bought brand 1 and 2 together

Tags: sql

I am trying to find unique customers in each brand and trying to find which customers have bought both the brands.

below is the query which I am suing:

```
WITH GROUPS AS (   

    SELECT 
     individual_id
    ,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT FML) = 1 THEN 'only '|| MAX(FML)
              ELSE 'cross'
              END AS GROUPS
    FROM DM_OWNER.transaction_detail_mv A JOIN sl_d1fml B ON A.SKU = B.SKU
    GROUP BY 
    individual_id
    )

    SELECT  
    g.GROUPS
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.individual_id) AS countIndv
    ,SUM(t.dollar_value_us)
    ,COUNT(t.transaction_number)
    ,SUM(t.quantity)
    FROM  DM_OWNER.transaction_detail_mv t
    JOIN GROUPS g
    ON t.individual_id = g.individual_id
    JOIN sl_d1fml C ON T.SKU = C.SKU
    WHERE BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'HT'
    AND t.is_merch = 1
    AND t.Line_Item_Amt_Type_Cd = 'S'
    AND TRUNC (t.TXN_DATE) between '01-JAN-18' AND '31-JAN-18'
    GROUP BY g.GROUPS;
```

I just wanted to know if the query is correct and if it would work if there are more than 2 FML's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**
Get all the brands for the individual.

In older databases I used `wmsys.wm_concat` but that appears to be out of date, replaced by `listagg`

Here is a query that worked in your dbfiddle. You can add to it to get the rest of the columns you want.

```
select individual_id, 
rtrim( regexp_replace((listagg(brand_org_code , '-') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY brand_org_code)), 
           '([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', 
           '\1\3'),
         '-') as brands, 
sum(dollar_value_us) dollar_sum
from transaction_detail_mv 
group by individual_id
```

**Second**
Use it as a sub-query.

```
select brands, sum(dollar_sum)
from (select individual_id, 
rtrim( regexp_replace((listagg(brand_org_code , '-') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY brand_org_code)), 
           '([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', 
           '\1\3'),
         '-') as brands, 
sum(dollar_value_us) dollar_sum
from transaction_detail_mv 
group by individual_id) table1
group by brands
```